# i m not able to load the view file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3, hmvc, hmvc-codeigniter

this is store_items controller

```
<?php 
class store_items extends MX_Controller 
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    function create(){
        $this->load->library('session');

        $this->load->module('site_security');
        $this->site_security->_make_sure_is_admin();
        $data['view_module'] = "store_items";
        $data['view_file'] = "create";
        $this->load->module('templates');
        $this->templates->admin($data);
    }
```

This is create.php

```
  <h1>Add new items</h1>
```

I'm not able to load create.php file in the browser create file is not loaded
 what is the issue in loading the view file. The view file ie create is not loading in the browser. I should see Add new items in the create file.

Comment: 1) Reformat your post to remove the text from the code. 2) Mention what kind of errors you are getting while running the code 3) Also mention values of different variables while a debug run through.

Comment: @NitinSingh is it a correct way to load the view file $data['view_file'] = "create";

Comment: To load a particular view file you will use the following method:

`$this->load->view('name');`. Please check the reference here: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i know this but what this code is doing  $data['view_module'] = "store_items";

Comment: What is the exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: @MayankPandeyz what is $data['view_file ']= "create"; what this code is doing ? what is view_file and create is called ?

Comment: First of all please let me know what is the exact issue you are facing ?

Comment: i m not able to load the view file create.php in controller store_items using method create